# Uso seguro de contraseñas en java

Tags: java, seguridad

sé que la pregunta es extraña, pero hace unos días hicimos unas pruebas con unos colegas para comprobar hasta qué punto era complicado obtener información sensible de un programa en ejecución.

La prueba fue la siguiente:

1- Crear una máquina virtual con 1G de ram

2- Un programa en java que contuviese un string y desbordase la memoria para forzar que se guardase la información en la memoria swap.

3- Apagar la máquina virtual a lo bestia, entrar con una live y recuperar la información.

Se que la prueba tiene fallos y que en un caso practico seria mas difícil, pero el caso es que resulto tremendamente sencillo obtener la cadena de texto con un simple “strings” apuntando a la swap.

La pregunta es la siguiente ¿Existe alguna forma de ocultar u ofuscar esta información de tal forma que si un atacante accede a la maquina sea lo más difícil posible obtener esta información?

Si necesitais mas datos de la prueba la puedo documentar

Comment: Lo que necesitas es nunca guardar la contraseña de ninguna manera. Por qué harías eso? El punto de las contraseñas es que solo la tenga el usuario... no tu programa. De todas maneras... si un atacante tiene acceso físico a tu máquina, lo que menos me preocuparía a mi es que se ponga a hurgar en la memoria... le es mucho más fácil hacer un dump de tus contraseñas guardadas en windows o en el navegador... Credenciales, tarjetas de crédito, acceso directo a tu email para aceptar/solicitar cambios de contraseñas de los sitios donde no pueda entrar directamente...

Comment: De todas maneras (y suponiendo que donde dices SOAP te refieres a SWAP), un programa real no tendrá una única variable que desbordará, y te encontrarías más bien con un montón de trozos de strings que no sabrás de dónde vienen exactamente. Es posible que una contraseña (o tal vez un token revocable, que sería más correcto) estén ahí guardados... pero no sé si sería tan fácil. A ver si alguien con más conocimientos en seguridad puede aclararlo, porque me parece interesante. También siéntete libre de documentar todo lo específico que quieras, cuantos más datos más interesante :)

Comment: Como comenta @Benito-B, cualquier atacante que tenga acceso físico a una máquina pude obtener cualquier tipo de dato  de las aplicaciones (y no solo de la aplicaciones Java) ya que todos los programas al fin y al cabo cargan sus datos en la RAM y/o en disco. ¿Cómo podrías no recuperar la cadena en texto plano?: 1) Encripta las contraseñas antes de cargarlas en memoria (difícil, ya que antes de cifrar cualquier dato debe cargarlo en la memoria, aunque sea a trozos), pero ¿y que pasa con la llave? y 2) Carga la contraseña en una arreglo de _bytes_ (esto es muy fácil revertirlo).

Comment: En resumen: poco o nada puedes hacer en materia de seguridad para evitar que un atacante con acceso físico a tu máquina no pueda obtener todo tipo de información.